# Column Names in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
select 
(select GETDATE()) as Date,
(select ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2) as "Photo" 
from 
      inventoryinfo, 
      InventoryStoreInfo 
WHERE 
      InventoryCategoryID IN 
      ('3','6','19','22','23','40','32','56','52','41'))
```

The results are fine, but the column names do not work for the "Photo" column.  The Date does show.  Photo reads (No Column Name) instead.

Comment: Have you tried using `as Photo` or `as [Photo]`? What database are you using - MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle or something else? I believe the query could be re-written (and `select ROUND` appears to be missing an ending parenthesis)

Comment: post the exact error..

Comment: Do you want the column name to contain the quotes? If not, you can simply remove them.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
(select GETDATE()) as Date,
(select 
    ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2)
from 
      inventoryinfo, 
      InventoryStoreInfo 
WHERE 
      InventoryCategoryID IN 
      ('3','6','19','22','23','40','32','56','52','41')
 ) as Photo
```

Comment: Perfect!  I was also able to add my additional queries to this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select  GETDATE() AS [Date]
        ,ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2) as [Photo]
        ,ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2) as COG_Facilities -- Add other outputs here
from 
      inventoryinfo, 
      InventoryStoreInfo 
WHERE 
      InventoryCategoryID IN 
      ('3','6','19','22','23','40','32','56','52','41')
```

Comment: Cool. Removed the last ) from the answer.

Comment: So this was just the first column, if I have more to add such as,  (select ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2) as COG_Facilities from inventoryinfo, InventoryStoreInfo 
WHERE InventoryCategoryID IN ('11','18','36')
and inventoryinfo.inventoryitemID = inventorystoreinfo.inventoryitemid

I have about 10 columns to add

Comment: You don't need to make a subquery as they are coming from one query. you can easily add the rest of your columns to the `SELECT`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look you have used double quotes(" ") for photo . No need to double quotes(" ") just use Photo

Your code may like

```
select 
(select GETDATE()) as Date,
(select ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2) as Photo
from inventoryinfo, InventoryStoreInfo
WHERE InventoryCategoryID IN('3','6','19','22','23','40','32','56','52','41'))
```

Comment: The double quotes was just a test.  With and without the quotes the column name lists as

(No Column Name)

Answer (score 0):

You lose the "photo" column name since you are using subtables and the name is only visible inner select scope.

`ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2) as "Photo"` is nested inside `(select ...)` so the outer select cannot see "photo". Only the sum subtable has the name "Photo", not the entire Round subtable.

Just add the name to the entire subtable that you want to be named "photo":

```
select 
    (select GETDATE()) as Date,
    (select (ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice), 2) as Photo
            from inventoryinfo, InventoryStoreInfo
            WHERE InventoryCategoryID
            IN ('3','6','19','22','23','40','32','56','52','41')
        ) as photo )
```

Your real problem is though that you are creating subtables for no reason. Remove the extra selects and it will be much easier to keep track of what each lable is referring to:

```
select 
    GETDATE() as Date,
    ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice), 2) as Photo
            from inventoryinfo, InventoryStoreInfo
            WHERE InventoryCategoryID
            IN ('3','6','19','22','23','40','32','56','52','41')
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ... this is test code and it  works for sql server 2008

```
select 
(select GETDATE()) as 'Date',
(select b.tp) as 'Price'
from 
      ProductInfo a, 
      product_detail b

      where b.tp in (2,3,4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have placed alias at wrong place, check out the Braces from where you have started and where it gonna complete.

```
select 
(select GETDATE()) as Date,
(select ROUND(sum(QuantityInStore * AveragePrice),2)
from 
      inventoryinfo, InventoryStoreInfo 
WHERE 
      InventoryCategoryID IN 
      ('3','6','19','22','23','40','32','56','52','41')) as Photo
```